# How to generate a hospital perimeter database

Tags: data

I have about 2500 hospital points with names and addresses across the nation. My goal is to create a polygon layer of perimeters for these hospitals. The perimeter shape should look like what's in Google Map. Below is an example.

What's the best way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: This is not a trivial undertaking -- you'd need to heads-up digitize or run raster to vector conversion for each campus.  Either way, this question is quite broad, and therefore not ideal for the "Focused Question/Best Answer" model used here in GIS SE.

Comment: "Best" is not a well-defined concept. Cheap, quick, good: choose two at most. Cheap and quick (100m circle) would not be good. Cheap and good (I'll survey all your hospitals to 100cm accuracy but it will take me ten years) is not quick. If you want it done in a week I could hire 1000 people but it will cost you (quick and good).

Comment: Do you need to use Google Maps? OpenStreetMap has the building polygon perimeter ready to export example 'inova loudoun hospital' see https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3772191

Comment: Thank you Mapperz. After confirming with the client, I think tax parcel boundaries are what she is looking for. But this is very good to know. It may help with my other projects.

Comment: Hey - you can use [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) to access the [Hospital Area Tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dhospital) and the following code (just copy and paste it into Overpass Turbo)
`area
  [amenity=hospital]
  ({{bbox}});
out;`
[Complete Version Here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/cPI)

Comment: You might want to look at the dataset of [Hospital Boundaries](http://www.maponics.com/hospital-boundaries) available from Maponics. (disclaimer - I work there).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about the US (since your example is from the US) I would:

1. Look for parcel data for the county that each hospital occurs in,
2. Then select all the parcels that intersect with your points
3. Then export all the selected parcels to a new dataset

Odds are the property boundaries on file with the county assessor are a pretty good match for what is in Google Maps.  Most, but not all, counties have their parcel data available for download as a shapefile or geodatabase.  Sometimes the data is only available at a cost from a third-party.  Also, each of those sets of parcel data is likely to be in some local state-plane projection/datum so you'll have to get everything back to some common system.

It is going to be a pile of work to get all that parcel data but as far as I know there isn't a national level parcel database anywhere.  You may also have some luck getting the data from a source like OpenStreetMap but that will depend on how much, and how accurately, features have been digitized for each area.

The real brute-force option would be to use aerial imagery and trace out the boundaries yourself.  2500 points isn't completely unmanageable, it would take a fair amount of time but it's not impossible.  This might actually be the most straightforward since you wouldn't have to scour the internet looking through county GIS websites and messing around with projections.

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin. This is in line with what I have in mind. I guess there is no way to get the digital data directly from Google or any other sources?

Comment: Just found this thread  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44831/source-for-us-parcel-boundary-data

Comment: To my knowledge Google is pretty locked down.  OpenStreetMap would be worth checking out but it will really depend on how much work has been done in an area.